# ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to push my local files to remote origin getting this error message. I don't know how to resolve this please help!

```
$ git push -u origin --all
ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Just make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: gitlab.com is known for its lag and instability. Check status.gitlab.com as well as try it again later.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check https://status.gitlab.com/ for the status of **Git Operations**
2. If GitLab is up, check the SSH connection directly:

   `ssh -vvv git@gitlab.com`

   (you can test this with your own [SSH key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#use-ssh-keys-to-communicate-with-gitlab) registered at gitlab.com)

   The debugging output here will help you in diagnosing SSH or network problems
3. If this is okay, check that the version of your `git` client is up-to-date, either the latest, or at least the [version built and included by GitLab/Gitaly](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitaly/-/blob/master/Makefile#L146) (git v2.35.1 when I write this answer).